# Examples of non-measurable sets(Lebesgue)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I made this post because i would like to see some examples of non-measurable sets with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}^d$

A first example is the classical Vitaly set.

Another example which involves dynamical systems is this:

> Let $([0,1),\mathcal{B},m,T)$ where $Tx=(x+a)mod1=\{x+a\}=x+a-[x+a]$ where $a \in \Bbb{R}\setminus \Bbb{Q}$
>
> $T$ is an irrational rotation.
>
> Every orbit $\{T^nx|n \in \Bbb{Z}\}$ is infinite for all $x \in [0,1)$
>
> We use the axiom of choice and we construct the set $A \subseteq [0,1)$ which contains exactly $\text{one}$ element of every orbit of $T$
>
> In other words $\forall x \in [0,1)$  exists unique $m \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $T^mx \in A$
>
> It is clear that $A$ is uncountable.
>
> Not let $B_i=T^i(A)$.
>
> It is not difficult to see that $B_i \cap B_j=\emptyset,\forall i \neq j$ in $\Bbb{Z}$
>
> Now if $A$ is Lebesgue measurable then:
>
> $m(\bigcup_{i \in \Bbb{Z}}B_i)=\sum_{i \in \Bbb{Z}}m(B_i)=\sum_{i \in \Bbb{Z}}m(A)$ because the Lebesgue measure is translation-invariant(or $T-$invariant).
>
> Also $1=m(\bigcup_{i \in \Bbb{Z}}B_i)$ because $\bigcup_{i \in \Bbb{Z}}B_i=[0,1)$
>
> Thus if we assume that $m(A)>0$ or $m(A)=0$ we easily derive a contradiction.
>
> Thus $A$ is not Lebesgue measurable.

Can someone provide me other interesting example of non-Lebesgue measureable set in $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{R}^d$ in general?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Measure and Category by Oxtoby](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387905082), Chapter $5,$ the author stated that [Bernstein set](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/bernstein-set/) is non-measurable (Theorem $5.4$).

Comment: +1...this is a nice example...unfortunately i do not know ordinal theory to understand the construction...but still good

Comment: @MariosGretsas: You can treat ordinal as generalisation of natural number. In other word, you can imagine constructing Bernstein set using natural numbers instead.

Comment: I will try that..thanks for the answer.